# JIRA - Excel report to include the date an issue entered a particular status (trying to calculate cycle time)

Tags: jira

When running a search on JIRA I can export the results to Excel and see dates and times of when the issue was Created,Resolved and First Response. I would also like to be able to see the date the item entered the status "In Dev" in this Excel export.

Would I need to create a custom field? If so, how would I go about creating a field that automatically gets populated with this data?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think Custom Field is the best solution here, one question, based on how your workflow is defined (and restricted) an issue might flow between two states multiple times. For eg. from "In Dev" it might go to "In Review" then be sent back to "In Dev" state and so on. How do you want the report in that case, should it show all these transition dates? Or just the date it moved to the current state it is in now?

Comment: I would just like to know the first time it moves into the status of "In Dev" if things move back and forth from test to review etc. back to dev that's fine. I don't need those recorded I just need to know the first time it went into "in dev" without it being overwritten if it moves across statuses.